# How to enable caching on in-memory Kafka Streams state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to decrease the number of data being sent downstream, and since I only care about the last value of a given key, I'm reading data from a topic this way:

```
KTable table = build.table("inputTopic", Materialized.as("myStore"));
```

Why? Because under the hood, the data is being cached, as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-63%3A+Unify+store+and+downstream+caching+in+streams), and forwarded only if the *commit.interval.ms* or *cache.max.bytes.buffering* kicks in.

So far so good, but since in this case I'm not taking advantage of RocksDB at all, so I'd like to replace it with the default implementation of an in-memory store. I implicitly enable caching, just in case.

```
Materialized.as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("myStore")).withCachingEnabled();
```

It doesn't work, though - the data is not being cached and every record is being sent downstream.

Is there another way to enable caching? Or perhaps there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: This should work as you expect it... Not sure why it does not for you. Just to double check: you did not set `cache.max.bytes.buffering` to zero? To further debug this, can you set a breakpoint in `KTableSourceProcessor#init` (nested class within `KTableSource`) and check the class/type of the used key-value store? It should be a `CachingKeyValue` store.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax cache.max.bytes.buffering was set to 100MB. I wrote MCVE which tests reading from a topic to a KTable and an aggregate operation, both with in-memory cached stores... and they indeed work as expected :) It must have been some silly mistake of mine.

Do you think I should delete my question or answer it with MCVE which shows that I was wrong?

Comment: Glad it works and it's not a bug :) -- Guess it's up to you if you want to delete the question or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I was wrong and in-memory state store caching works as expected. I'll briefly show how I've tested it, perhaps someone will find it useful. I made a very basic Kafka Streams application that just reads from a topic abstracted as a KTable.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

        builder.table("inputTopic", Materialized.as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("myStore")).withCachingEnabled())
                .toStream()
                .foreach((k, v) -> logger.info("Result: {} - {}", k, v));

        new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), getProperties()).start();
    }

    private static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testApp");
        properties.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
        properties.put(CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 10 * 1024 * 1024L);
        properties.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Then I ran the console producer from Kafka:

```
/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic inputTopic --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"
```

And sent few messages: a:a, a:b, a:c. Only the last message of them was visible in the app, so the cache works as expected.

> 2018-03-06 21:21:57 INFO  Main:26 - Result: a - c

I've also changed the stream slightly to check the caching of `aggregate` method.

```
builder.stream("inputTopic")
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(() -> "", (k, v, a) -> a + v, Materialized.as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("aggregate")))
        .toStream()
        .foreach((k, v) -> logger.info("Result: {} - {}", k, v));
```

I've sent few messages in rapid succession with the same key, and I've received just a single result, so the data was not being sent downstream right away - exactly as intended.